# h:outputStylesheet and client-side conditional comments

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, jsf-2, conditional-comments

I don't expect somebody has an answer for this question but is there a good way to use JSF `h:outputStylesheet` with client-side [conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx) for Internet Explorer?

I know `h:outputStylesheet` puts a `link` element at the end of the `head` instead of the place where I write a `h:outputStylesheet` and it is out of any conditional comments. Do I need to stick to conventional `link` elements to use conditional comments? (I also know I can use `h:outputText` to output conditional comments so it is not a problem here.)

I already know OminiFaces has a tag for conditional comments but it does not work for `h:outputStylesheet` so I asked if there is another way to make conditional comments work for such JSF tags.

Comment: That's correct. You can't defer the conditional comment to be wrapped around the deferred link element.

Comment: That is probably I must write my own tag library if I want to use client-side conditional comments.

Comment: Oh, I finally understand I can use `#{resource[...]}` to get the location of a resource and avoid `h:outputStylesheet` at all. Thank you for pointing out.